# How can I move all non-hidden .jpeg files using shell expansion characters?

Tags: command-line

Here is my problem:

> Move all non-hidden files with names ending with .jpg (regardless of
> case - .jpg, .JPG, .JpG etc.) from your present working directory into
> /tmp.
>
> Use shell expansion characters to accomplish this.

Shell expressions are not my thing, I wonder how I can do this. Suggestions?

Comment: This question will likely get closed a homework

Comment: +1 or at least as *too broad* **unless** you can narrow it down to a specific issue you are having trouble with

Comment: @raven2313 Does "non-hidden" just mean "files not starting with `.`"? Do you need to move only files located *directly* in the present working directory to `/tmp`, or do you also need to move files from *subdirectories* of the present working directory (and subdirectories of the subdirectories, etc.)? Should a new subdirectory of `/tmp` be created for them (e.g., `/tmp/jpgs`), or should they go directly in `/tmp`? What should happen if there is already a file of the same name in `/tmp` as one of the files being moved? Should `.jpeg` files also be moved? Why *must* the solution use shell globs?

Comment: Close-voters: Though I sympathize with the impulse to close this, we don't actually have a policy of closing homework questions on our site, and the limited ambiguity in this question is similar to the ambiguity in *most* questions--this is not *really* too broad. Fundamentally, writing partially or fully case-insensitive shell globs is both a useful topic and a sufficiently narrow one to address in AU format, and having this question open and answered contributes to [our site's primary task of building a library of reusable questions and answers about Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

#### You can use a shell pattern with `[` `]` character classes.

To move each file (and folder)

- that is located directly in the present working directory, *and*
- whose name does *not* start with a `.` (i.e., the file is not hidden), *and*
- whose name ends with `.jpg` or one of its seven other case variants (like `.JPG` or `.Jpg`)

to `/tmp`, you can use the command:

```bash
mv -- *.[Jj][Pp][Gg] /tmp
```

- This uses [character classes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#Ranges) to match any files whose names end in `.`, then `J` or `j`, then `P` or `p`, then `G` or `g`. Character classes (with `[` `]`) use more compact syntax than brace expressions (`{` `}`), and also have the benefit that they only expand to names of files that actually exist, so you won't get error messages even if some case variants of `.jpg` don't appear at the end of any filenames. (You'll still see an error message if *no* files are matched.)
- When the shell expands patterns, it excludes files that begin with `.` by default, so nothing special has to be done to achieve that.
- The `--` option ensures `mv` interprets everything after it as a filename and not as an option. Thus even if the pattern matches files whose names start with `-`, they will be treated as literal filenames and not options to `mv`. (This could alternatively have been achieved by prefixing the pattern with `./`, i.e. `mv ./*.[Jj][Pp][Gg] /tmp`.)

#### You can enable the `nocaseglob` shell option and give a simple pattern.

An alternative way is to turn on the [`nocaseglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nocaseglob_.28since_bash_2.02-alpha1.29) [shell option](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), which causes filename patterns to matched case-insensitively. Since you likely don't need to change this setting for subsequent commands, you can surround the commands that enable `nocaseglob` and move the files in parentheses so they [run in a subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), so that [the calling environment](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment) is unaffected:

```bash
(shopt -s nocaseglob; mv -- *.jpg /tmp)
```

Since `jpg` is only three characters long, you may prefer the above method with character classes. However, for case-sensitive globbing of longer words, it becomes quite handy to be able to set `nocaseglob`.

#### What happens if there are files with the same name already in `/tmp`?

However you decide to specify the pattern of files to be moved, if a file with the same name as one of the files being moved already exists in `/tmp`, then `mv`'s default behavior will be followed, as we have not given `mv` any options about how to handle a collision. That is to say:

- If the pre-existing destination file has write permissions for the user running `mv`, it will be automatically and silently overwritten by the source file.
- If the pre-existing destination file does not have write permissions for the user running `mv`, then `mv` will prompt the user and ask what to do. (Overwriting the file might still succeed in this case, if the user owns the pre-existing destination file.)

To specify different behavior when the destination file already exists, you can use the `--backup`, `-b`, `-f`, `-i`, `-n`, or `-u` options, as documented in:

- [`man mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/mv.1.html) *and*
- [11.4 mv: Move (rename) files](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#mv-invocation) (in the [GNU coreutils reference manual](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/)).

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
mv ./*.{j,J}{p,P}{g,G} /path/to/folder/
```

or alternatively

```
mv "$(pwd)"/*.{j,J}{p,P}{g,G} /path/to/folder/
```

Comment: @Serg This looks mostly okay, but standard error shouldn't be redirected to `/dev/null` in this situation. Presumably if there is an error the user will want to know about it. And if a destination file already exists with the same name as a file being moved *and the destination file does not have write permissions*, then by default `mv` will prompt the user to ask what to do. The message shown to the user in this situation *is written to standard error, not standard output*, so the command may appear to stall (and respond in an undesirable way to user input) unless `2> /dev/null` is removed.

Comment: @EliahKagan So what can be done about the messages when the mv command doesn't find a file for specific file extension ? Doesn't this also belong to stderr ?

Comment: Potentially you could filter them out specifically by piping all the output (`|&`) to  a (very carefully written) `grep` command. Or something. In practice, you should probably either ignore them, or write the command in such a way as not to produce them. For example, the command in [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617099/22949) uses character classes rather than brace expansion. Or if you're willing to run the risk of a confusing error message when *no* files match, you could turn on `shopt nullglob`.

Comment: @EliahKagan  `mv ./*.{j,J}{p,P}{g,G} /path/to/folder/  2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -v 'No such file or directory'   `    How's that ?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841/3701431

Comment: For this purpose, you can use `|&` instead of `2>&1 >/dev/null |`. But I don't recommend adding complexity to silence these errors. Really, these difficulties arise because brace expansion isn't the best way. If the errors are considered a problem, one can simply choose a method that doesn't produce them. Your suggested command will silently appear to succeed even when *no* source file exists. If that is considered acceptable, I suggest using nullglob instead. (But then, if you're going to set shopts, you could set nocaseglob instead and use a much simpler pattern; see the edit to my answer.)